# Macro keeps crashing Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro that compares a general list of dates (Sheet1) with a list of "business dates" where the office is open(COF). So if a date on the general list is not on the business dates list, my macro should try to find the closest business date to the date on the general list and assign it to the column to the right. The contents in the cells are formatted identically as dates. Unfortunately, Excel completely freezes every time I try to run the macro and I have to force quit, without an error message or anything.

```
Sub BusinessDate()
'Finds the closest business date to a lease date, solving for weekends
Dim businessday As Boolean
Dim shift As Integer

For Each Cell1 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B10000")
'Change 10000 to maximum number of rows if > 10000 rows
    businessday = False

    For Each Cell2 In Worksheets("COF").Range("A2:A10000")

        If Cell1.Value = Cell2.Value Then
            businessday = True
            Cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell1.Value
        End If

    Next Cell2
    shift = 1
    Do While businessday = False And shift < 6

        For Each Cell2 In Worksheets("COF").Range("A2:A10000")

            If Cell1.Value + shift = Cell2.Value Then
                businessday = True
                Cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell1.Value + shift
                Exit Do
            End If

        Next Cell2

        For Each Cell2 In Worksheets("COF").Range("A2:A10000")

            If Cell1.Value - shift = Cell2.Value Then
                businessday = True
                Cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell1.Value - shift
            End If

        Next Cell2
        shift = shift + 1
        Loop
    Next Cell1
End Sub
```

Did I write something wrong in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `ElseIf` or `Case` to shorten this. May help you follow your logic better and see your issue

Comment: Since you're cycling through a lot of cells, if you don't have to worry about people attempting to use Excel while this is running, you could try adding `DoEvents` before each `Next` line......

Comment: Also, change `A10,000` to a dynamic last row. Limit your loops to least amount necessary.

Comment: Perhaps turn calculation to manual and screenupdating to off at the start?  What if you also instead used Arrays to store the data, then compare it, and keep a record of those cells that are equal?  Also do you really need to run it over 10,000 rows, twice?  (Or, wouldn't that really be 10,000 * 10,000 since you're checking each cell in the row, against the entire other column, then moving to the second cells, etc.)

Comment: Do you really have 10,000 dates to check? That's almost 30 years worth of data (a lot more for business dates). You're currently doing 10,000 * 10,000 comparisons, which is 100,000,000 operations. If you can cut your sheets down to unique dates it will save you a lot of processing time.

Comment: *So if a date on the general list is not on the business dates list, my macro should try to find the closest business date to the date on the general list and assign it to the column to the right.* see `vlookup` with exact match set to False. Should return date right before actual date if exact match not found.

Comment: Also, in your first loop, you don't end the loop if the date is found. That should speed things up considerably. However, you might want to use a lookup instead of that loop.

Comment: My macro now runs in a reasonable amount of time! I'm now using a dynamic last row variable and an Exit For statement in the first loop to speed up the macro. Thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the loops were too large, and Excel wasn't crashing but instead was taking an extremely long time to complete the macro. You can shorten the process by using variables to represent the last row of data in each sheet as follows:

```
Dim lastrowsheet1 As Integer   
lastrowsheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").End(xlDown).row        
For Each Cell1 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrowsheet1)
```

Also, including an Exit For statement to avoid looping through the rest of a range of cells after a match has been found greatly reduces the time needed for the macro to finish:

```
If Cell1.Value = Cell2.Value Then 
    businessday = True 
    Cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell1.Value 
    Exit For 
End If
```

Also, DoEvents is helpful if you know the user won't use Excel while the macro is running